# elif statment in python 3.3.2 not working as intended

Tags: python-3.x

```
if choice == 'moments':
    moments()
    elif choice == 'kinetic energy':
        kineticEnergy()
        elif choice == 'gravitational potential energy':
            gravtPotent()
            else :
                print('incorrect option')
```

so it just keep saying sytax error or invalid sytax, there more code before this and after this.
so this is either me not knowing how to use it or my idle is glicthed out. i using the defualt ide
-idle that is given when i downloaded it. i using 3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Elif should be out of indentation. The following will work as intended

```
if choice == 'moments':
    moments()
elif choice == 'kinetic energy':
    kineticEnergy()
elif choice == 'gravitational potential energy':
    gravtPotent()
else :
    print('incorrect option')
```

Comment: thx for the help, i also fixed anothe mistake i have made thanks.